# No nested arrays with recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

The following function where `$data` is made of objects/arrays representing the results extracted from a database:

```
public function build_tree($data, $parent_id = '0')
{
    $tree = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

        if ($value->parent_id === $parent_id) { //build array
            $tree[] = $value; 

            // using recursion
            $children = $this->build_tree($data, $value->id);

            if ($children) { // build array
                $tree[] = $children; 
            }
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}
```

Gives me nested array like so:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'id' => string '16' (length=2)
      public 'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Test 3' (length=6)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'order' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[35]
          public 'id' => string '18' (length=2)
          public 'parent_id' => string '16' (length=2)
          public 'title' => string '- Novo' (length=6)
          public 'excerpt' => string 'dfgdfg' (length=6)
          public 'content' => string 'dfgdfg' (length=6)
          public 'order' => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[31]
              public 'id' => string '14' (length=2)
              public 'parent_id' => string '18' (length=2)
              public 'title' => string '- - Test 1.1.1' (length=14)
              public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
              public 'order' => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[34]
      public 'id' => string '17' (length=2)
      public 'parent_id' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'title' => string 'Test 666' (length=8)
      public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'order' => string '8' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[32]
          public 'id' => string '15' (length=2)
          public 'parent_id' => string '17' (length=2)
          public 'title' => string '- Test 2' (length=8)
          public 'excerpt' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'content' => string '' (length=0)
          public 'order' => string '4' (length=1)
```

Is it possible to build the new array without nesting? But still maintain the correct order and the father - children relation? Meaning all children elements would still come right after its father index but without being nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to return flat list, just replace:

```
$children = $this->build_tree($data, $value->id);
```

with:

```
$tree = array_merge($tree, $this->build_tree($data, $value->id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your result tree:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($tree as $parent) {

   if (is_object($parent)) {

      $newArray[] = $parent;

   } else if (is_array($parent)) {

      foreach ($parent as $child) {

          $newArray[] = $child;

      }

   }

}
```

That should do the job.